# What is the advised output method to upload a 180 degree VR work to YouTube

Tags: video, file-format

[image]

I want to upload a 180 degree VR work to YouTube.
What is the advised output method.

The VR I want to do is a two-eye VR screen, this VR is immersive when viewed with a headset, but not 360 degree VR.

What output methods are available using Blender 2.8?

I searched but found nothing helpful, what I want to make is something like an attached image.

Englis is not my first language.

Comment: Start with the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/multiview/index.html and look at the options for Side-By-Side and Cross-Eyed. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to create! By setting Side-By-Side and Cross-Eyed. Thank you very much!